# Using SunStudio dbxtool on Red Hat Linux.

Tags: linux, debugging, dbx

Using sunstudio12.1 dbxtool on Red Hat Linux.  I am able to use dbx command line interface from sunstudio12.1/bin directory to debug a Linux executable.
However when I try to use sunstudio12.1/bin/dbxtool I get "wrong architecture" dbx and dbxtool are located in the same directory and are pathed correctly. 
Am I trying to do the impossible?  Or is there a trick to get this to work?